# You must set ShopifyAPI::Base.api_version before making a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, shopify

I've received the above error when following the guides from Shopify to create a Rails app. None of the other solutions worked and I followed the Shopify guide to the tee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the Shopify Rails app from github, I saw that they had this in their shop model:

```
def api_version
   ShopifyApp.configuration.api_version
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you made an API call without opening up a valid session. A session opens when you provide a shop domain, its API token, and the version of the API you expect to use.

If you fail to open a session, and make a call, you get that message. So inspect your code, and ensure you have a session. The convenience method is used all over the place, first get a shop instance, then use the method **with_shopify_session**. Your problem will then go away. You can also hot-rod this for NON typical use cases, by making a similar method **with_api_session** that mimics the Shopify call, allowing you to function with your own codes, where perhaps you are not directly installed an App but still have API keys. Think private Apps.